# Proving a two variable limit using $\epsilon- \delta$ approach.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I came across a question in which we had to prove the following limit by $\epsilon-\delta$ approach:

> $\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,-1)}xy-2x^2=-1$

I had to prove that: For every $\epsilon>0$ in  $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}<\epsilon$, there exists a corresponding $\delta$ such that $|xy-2x^2+1|< \delta$. So, I proceeded by putting $x+1=x_1$ and $y+1=y_1$ so that it would simplify the former expression inside the square root and would also help me to convert it to polar. However, neither of the methods worked and I ran out of ideas. I am new to multivariable calculus and am using $\epsilon-\delta$ approach in two variables for the first time.

Would someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try proving that $\lim fg=\lim f\cdot\lim g$ and $\lim(f+g)=\lim f+\lim g$.

Comment: @KentaS Actually it is mentioned in the Question to prove it by $\epsilon-\delta$ only. Can it be done by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x_1,y_1$ so small as $x_1^2+y_1^2<1$
\begin{align*}
|xy-2x^2+1|&=|(x_1-1)(y_1-1)-2(x_1-1)^2+1|\\&=|x_1y_1-(x_1+y_1)+1-2x_1^2-2+4x_1+1|\\
&\le \color{blue}{|x_1||y_1|}+|x_1+y_1|+2x_1^2+4|x_1|\\
&\le \color {blue}{(\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2})^2}+6\sqrt {x_1^2+y_1^2}+2(x_1^2+y_1^2)\\&=\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2} (6+3\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2})\\&\lt 9\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2}=9\sqrt{(x+1)^2+(y+1)^2}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much Koro!

Comment: @Shashwat1337: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
xy-2x^2+1 &= (x+1-1)(y+1-1)-2(x+1-1)^2+1\\
&=(x+1)(y+1)-(x+1)-(y+1)-2(x+1)^2+4(x+1)\\
&=(x+1)(y+1)+3(x+1)-(y+1)-2(x+1)^2
\end{align}

We choose $\delta < 1$,

then we know that $$|xy-2x^2+1| \le \delta^2 + 3\delta + \delta + 2\delta = 7\delta$$

Now, I will leave the task of  choosing $\delta$ as a function of $\epsilon$ to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but unfortuately I can accept only one answer.

Comment: no worries. hope you can solve the problem :)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I did  :)